# Книги по iOS и Objective-С

Tags: ios, objective-c, книги

Расскажите, с каких книг вы начинали изучение objective-c. Я пока только [developer.apple.com](http://developer.apple.com) пользуюсь.

---

**Аналогичные вопросы, заданные на ХэшКоде позднее:**

[iOS Литература](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/232154/%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-ios-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0)

[Objective-C, Cocoa Touch - литература/мануалы/туториалы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/258344/ios-objective-c-cocoa-touch-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8B-%D1%82%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8B)

Comment: Я тоже :) Если уже есть бэкграунд в каком-то языке, особенно в c++, это оптимальный вариант.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вас интересует исключительно язык Objective-C(а изучение iOS-разработки лично я рекомендовал бы начать с изучения языка, даже если ранее писали на С, что даже лучше), то советую посмотреть на "Программирование на Objective-C" Стивена Кочана. Правда, там про 2-ую версию языка, но она на русском. Есть на amazonе английский вариант по 3-ей версии языка.

Answer (score 0):

Русскоязычных достойных книг по iOS я не встречала (по obj-c + Mac вроде что-то есть). А из англоязычных понравилось несколько книг:

1. iPhone SDK Development (The Pragmatic Programmers) - Bill Dudney, Christopher Adamson
2. iPhone Cool Projects - Wolfgang Ante, Gary Bennett, Benjamin Jackson
3. More iPhone Cool Projects - Ben Smith, Danton Chin, Claus Hofele

Answer (score 0):

От себя советую: [Programming in Objective-C 2.0](http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Objective-C-2-0-Stephen-Kochan/dp/0321566157) (к ней есть видео уроки в дополнение)
и [iPhone Programming: The Big Nerd Ranch Guide](http://www.bignerdranch.com/book/iphone_programming_the_big_nerd_ranch_guide) (конкретно по iOS, лучшая книга, имхо)

А вообще вот, тут куча ссылок на литературу и видео уроки: [Книги, видео и другие материалы по разработке под iOS](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/macosxdev/118282/).