# IOS литература

Tags: ios, objective-c, книги

Здравствуйте. Обращаюсь к знающим людям за помощью. Передо мной стоит диллема, с чего начать изучение `Objective-C` для последующей разработки под `iOS`. До этого год писал веб приложения на `Java EE`, то есть с ООП знаком не по наслышке. Итак у меня два вопроса:

1. Собственно с какой литературы начать
2. Какова по вашему мнению перспектива разработки под `iOS`, стоит ли? Или же стоит остаться на проекте `Java EE`. Или же продолжать изучать и то и то.
   Спасибо за ответы!

---

**Аналогичные вопросы, заданные на ХэшКоде позднее:**

[Лучшие книги по iOS и Objective-C](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1491/%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE-ios-%D0%B8-objective-c)

[Objective-C, Cocoa Touch - литература/мануалы/туториалы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/258344/ios-objective-c-cocoa-touch-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8B-%D1%82%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8B)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Странный вопрос какой-то.., сначала спрашиваешь про книги,а потом "стоит ли вообще?" - 
мое мнение: не уверен - не берись! 
Вот книги:
1) Стивен Кочан - Программирование на Objective-C 2.0(основы),
2) iOS 6 SDK. Разработка приложений для iPhone, iPad и iPod touch(примеры).