# Objective-C, Cocoa Touch - литература/мануалы/туториалы

Tags: ios, objective-c, книги

Доброе время суток!

Подскажите пожалуйста ссылочки/книги/статьи где можно прочитать о Cocoa | Cocoa Touch фреймворках, про их методы/функции и вообще, о тех, которые нужно знать при разработке под iOS/Mac OS. Буду очень благодарен Вам!

---

**Аналогичные вопросы, задававшиеся на ХэшКоде ранее:**

[Лучшие книги по iOS и Objective-C](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1491/%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE-ios-%D0%B8-objective-c)

[iOS Литература](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/232154/%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-ios-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Для себя отметил один неплохой ресурс (по мимо офф. документации): [Ссылка](http://www.extpost.com/category/objc/), думаю вам будет интересно почитать. А вообще читайте офф. документацию, там отлично всё расписано, если проблемы с иностранным языком - переводите гуглом, это во всяком случае быстрее и информация там всегда свежая.

Решил дописать несколько ссылок, думаю Вам и ещё многим людям пригодятся:

```
Официальная документация:
//iOS
```

- [Cocoa Touch Frameworks](https://developer.apple.com/technologies/ios/cocoa-touch.html)
- [Foundation Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/ObjC_classic/_index.html)
- [UIKit Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIKit_Framework/_index.html)
- [Game Kit Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GameKit_Collection/_index.html)
- [iAd Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Reference/iAd_ReferenceCollection/_index.html)
- [Map Kit Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MapKit_Framework_Reference/_index.html)
- [Core Data Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Reference/CoreData_ObjC/_index.html)

---

```
//Mac OS
```

- [Cocoa Frameworks](https://developer.apple.com/technologies/mac/cocoa.html)
- [Foundation Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/ObjC_classic/_index.html)
- [Application Kit Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/ObjC_classic/_index.html)
- [Core Foundation Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFOundation/Reference/CoreFoundation_Collection/_index.html)

Это конечно не всё, но есть о чём почитать.

---

Ещё несколько ссылок от себя:

- [Objective-C для начинающих - YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLDDC57722482A7C4E)
- [GeekyLemon - YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/user/GeekyLemon/videos)
- [iffytheperfect1983 - YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/user/iffytheperfect1983/videos)
- [1plahoff - YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/user/1plahoff/videos)
- [Основы программирования под iOS/Mac OS](http://macbug.ru)
- [Уроки/видео уроки/шпаргалки](http://www.imaladec.com)
- [Портал о разработке](http://touchdev.ru)
- [Есть что почитать](http://osxdev.ru)
- [Блог о разработке, хоть и не большой, но всё же](http://macsoj.wordpress.com)
- [Видео уроки от beSimple](http://besimple.ru)
- [Видео уроки от iPromix](http://podcast.ipromix.de)
- [Реалити-шоу «Научи меня XCODE». Уроки по разработке](http://appleinsider.ru/search?cx=partner-pub-6968868674851935%3A49rfe2v5oqx&cof=FORID%3A11&ie=UTF-8&q=реалити+шоу+научи+меня+xcode&sa.x=-1016&sa.y=-191)
- [Тут найдёте много много уроков/мануалов](http://www.raywenderlich.com)
- [Много кастомных элементов интерфейса](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls?page=6&sort=rating)
- [Использование Storyboard](http://habrahabr.ru/post/131128/)
- [Полезные штуки для iOS-разработчика #1](http://habrahabr.ru/post/144136/)
- [Objective-C как первый язык программирования](http://habrahabr.ru/post/167981/)
- [Хочешь быть iOS разработчиком? Будь им!](http://habrahabr.ru/post/149090/)
- [Objective-C с нуля](http://habrahabr.ru/post/107126/)
- [Записки iOS разработчика: Делимся опытом, часть 1](http://habrahabr.ru/post/192062/)
- [Core Data для iOS. Глава №1. Теоретическая часть](http://habrahabr.ru/post/191334/)
- [Разработка под iOS](http://habrahabr.ru/hub/ios_dev/)
- [Программирование на Objective-C - видео уроки](http://www.intuit.ru/studies/courses/4811/1058/info)
- [Видео уроки от Hexlet](http://hexlet.org/course/osx_dev/)

---

Список ссылок небольшой, но думаю Вам пригодиться, если ещё попадаются интиресные ссылки - обязательно сюда допишу.

Comment: Большое Вам спасибо за подборку ссылок, некоторые уже были, а некоторые пополнили мою коллекцию :)

Answer (score 5):

Чтобы все не перепечатывать [тут](http://habrahabr.ru/post/118282/) найдете много ссылок.
От себя:

**Книги:**

- С.Кочан - Programming in Objective-C 2.0 - подробный справочник по objc. (iOS)
- A.Хилегасс - Программирование на Cocoa (Mac OS X)

BecomeAnXcoder, Далримпл и иное ИМХО - мусор.

**Видеокурсы:**

- Все от Simon Allardice c [lynda.com](http://www.lynda.com/Simon-Allardice/21-1.html). На сайте платно, но на трекерах все найдете. Разжевывает прекрасно, поймет и слепой, нужно базовое понимание английского.
- Видеокурсы от Stanford University

Когда окрепнете - продолжить можно вот этими вещами:

- Pro Multithreading and Memory Management for iOS and OS X
- Carlo Chung (Apress) - Pro Objective-C Design Patterns for iOS - 2011
- Michael Privat, Robert Warner - Pro Core Data for iOS - Data Access and Persistence Engine for iPhone, iPad, and iPod touch - 2011

Comment: @AlexThumb, Спасибо Вам большое, будем гуглить :)

А не подскажите где именно про методы/функции фреймворках почитать?

Comment: На здоровье.
Методы/функции фреймворки - это в [документации][1] от Apple. Там все очень хорошо расписано, с примерами использования и кода. Доступ ко всему этому делу есть через органайзер Xcode, но там помедленее все работает чем через сеть (зато есть доступ оффлайн). Это при условии того что при установке Xcode вы скачали все дополнительные пакеты в Preferences - > Downloads


  [1]: http://developer.apple.com

Answer (score 4):

Добавлю от себя несколько качественных ресурсов для уже более, чем ещё только самых начинающих ;) (английский язык, никакого хабра, только то, о чём "точно нужно быть в курсе"):

---

**"Блоги"**

[NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/) - NSHipster is a journal of the overlooked bits in Objective-C and Cocoa. Updated weekly. Еженедельный блог о Objective-C & Cocoa одного из людей №1 в этой области.

[Mike Ash - Friday Q&A](http://mikeash.com/) - Один из самых-самых по своей глубине и качеству блогов. Блог огромного размера - автор обновляет его раз в неделю начиная с 2005 года.

[objc.io](http://www.objc.io/) - A periodical about best practices and advanced techniques in Objective-C.

- [Lighter View Controllers](http://www.objc.io/issue-1/)
- [Concurrent programming](http://www.objc.io/issue-2/)
- [Views](http://www.objc.io/issue-3/)
- [Core Data](http://www.objc.io/issue-4/)
- [iOS 7](http://www.objc.io/issue-5/)
- [Build tools](http://www.objc.io/issue-6/)
- [Foundation](http://www.objc.io/issue-7/)

[High Performance Core Data](http://highperformancecoredata.com/) - Learn how to analyze, debug, and squeeze every last bit of performance out of Core Data.

---

**Objective-C conventions**

Конвенции - это не только способ понять, как писать код чисто и правильно, но ещё часто и способ проникнуться тем, как создатели и участники такого рода проектов вообще мыслят о программировании. Кроме приведённых здесь конвенций есть ещё несколько - вы без труда их найдёте, если почувствуете вкус.

[Github Objective-C conventions](https://github.com/github/objective-c-conventions) - Coding conventions for Objective-C projects

[NYTimes Objective-C Style Guide](https://github.com/NYTimes/objective-c-style-guide) - The New York Times Mobile Team’s Objective-C Style Guide

[Google Objective-C Style Guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/objcguide.xml)

[What are best practices that you use when writing Objective-C and Cocoa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155964/what-are-best-practices-that-you-use-when-writing-objective-c-and-cocoa)

---

**GNUstep**

Наверное, все знают, что это open-source версия значительной части всей инфраструктуры Objective-C/Cocoa. Это хороший способ узнать о том, как хотя бы приблизительно написан [ваш любимый класс из фреймворка Cocoa Foundation](https://github.com/gnustep/gnustep-base/blob/master/Source/NSOperation.m). "Хотя бы приблизительно" потому, что код самой Apple скрыт от наших глаз, а GNUStep, хотя и делает всё то же самое, что и код Apple, тем не менее имеет немного другой код, поэтому это уже не совсем Apple.

---

P.S. Буду пополнять этот список по мере поступления хороших материалов.